# How to write WATIN scripts for a child window opened with window.open?

Tags: watin

I have a main menu window. On clicking any menu item it opens a child window using window.open? I am writing automated test script for this using Watin. How do i write Test script for the child windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Watin.Core.IE class has a static AttatchToIE method you can use.  It takes a Watin.Core.Constraint object as an argument (i.e. you have to use Find.ById, Find.ByName, etc.) to help Watin find the window you are looking for, and it returns a reference to an IE object.

Example:

```
IE myIE = IE.AttatchToIE(Find.ByTitle("Child Window Title"));
```

From there you can use the myIE object to run your tests, make sure it loads, make sure it has the expected text, etc.

Comment: This worked  

IE myIE = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("Child Window Title"));